# Change stage size at startup

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, resize, startup, stage

The problem is simple:
I want to read width and height from XML and then change the stage size based on these numbers in an EXE file of Flash. Imagine the main size of flash application is for example 1024 x786. I write a code which interact with user as touch screen and all startup data(like image file names and key coordination) come from an XML file. My problem is, for different PC`s, I must set the size of application manually. Some touch screens have different ratios like 1280 * 400! The only way is set the stage size on startup the application but`stage.staheWidth`and`stage.stageHeight`don`t change anything for me. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Adobe's doc:

"Air for TV devices have slightly different behavior than desktop devices when you set the stageHeight property. If the Stage.scaleMode property is set to StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE and you set the stageHeight property, the stage height does not change until the next frame of the SWF."

About resizing, you can still use the Resize event triggered when stage size change occurs and adapt your layout accordingly.

Comment: .. so basically I must make 2 frames and navigate from frame 1 to frame 2 for such an event called.